# asp.net insert a "like" to a comment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a comment system and i want to insert to a likes table a like
after the button was click.

the problem is that i don't know how to insert the like to the specific comment
the user was clicked for.

the comment system is an asp.net repeater.

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="repRequests" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="media CommentHeader">
             <h6 class="media-heading">
               <asp:Label ID="HeaderUserCom" Style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 14px;" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("user_name")%>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label ID="UserCom" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 600" Text='<%#Eval("comment")%>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" OnClick="btnLike_Click1" />
          </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
/asp:Repeater>
```

c# (insert the like to the likes table where comment id = @comment id)

```
    protected void btnLike_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into likes 
            select users.user_id, comments.comment_id where users.userName = @userName comments.comment_id = @comment", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Session["userName"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment_id", **what to put here ??**);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
```

Comment: take commentid in hidden field in repeater and pass it in event

Comment: That was what is was thinking of but how do i pass it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OnClick event needs to match the method name. You have `btnLike_Click` and `btnLIke_Click1`. Make them match.

To pass the comment ID, you can set it as the command argument on the button. This assumes the "comment_id" field is available in the data source you bound the repeater to.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" bOnClick="btnLike_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("comment_id")%>' />
```

Then retrieve it in your event handler.

```
protected void btnLike_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Button btn=sender as Button;
    if(btn!=null)
        {
        string comment_id=btn.CommandArgument;
        //perform the database insertion here
        }
    }
```

Comment: CommandArgument=Text='<%#Eval("comment_id")%>' /> not exceptionable

Comment: @GiladAdar That was a typo, see the corrected answer please.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfect ! i just have to change the string to int and convert the btn.CommandArgument to int as well, thanks !